# How to add a popover to table cell?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Actually I'm trying to show some data on single cell on hover inside a popover.
The issue is that what I'm trying to do is to add the data-toggle inside the `td` tag but it is having no effect.

Each cell look's like this:

```
<td style="padding: 0px; background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover"></td>
```

And the content is dynamic for each cell.

Obviously the function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({})   
});
```

is inside the code.

The following table look's like something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells need to have content to be rendered in most browsers. One way to handle this is to fill them with a non-breaking space. You can see in the code below that the popover works by simply adding the &nbsp; entity as the <td> element content.

```js
jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
 border: 1px solid #808080;
 min-width: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>33</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 2</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 4</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 5</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="padding: 0px; background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover">&nbsp;</td><td style="padding: 0px; background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover">&nbsp;</td><td style="padding: 0px; background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover">&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 6</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Tavolo 7</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: However, putting styling at element level would mean that you cannot cache the CSS style rules separately. Usually putting styles in CSS files would allow the caching to be done, thus reducing the amount of load from the server each time you load a page... you can even migrate it easier to external file by my meathod

Comment: And it still can be overridden by any stylesheet and what if you want to algorithmically change the style, do you intend to provide a class for every color combination? That will take a lot more bandwidth!

Comment: cache will help for that rather than loading all at the same page.

Comment: There are over 16 Million colors supported by HTML, and it takes more than 13 characters each, making your file over 208Mb, which is fine if you have no interest in being listed on google due to your pages loading slowly.

Comment: single css file can be easily understandable and used any where at many no of pages

Comment: You are simply wrong for dynamic styled pages.  If you want to deliver 208Mb css files, than go ahead, but don't try to teach other people to do things the wrong way. When you get to react/angular and animations you'll be completely unable to get anything done if you intend to stick with css files as a solution for everything. In many cases style information is best on the element.

Comment: I should also add that jQuery doesn't use stylesheets when adjusting colors of an element, it changes the style of the element, because when setting the color of one element, that is the RIGHT thing to do.

Comment: if you have a good css file u can use it any where like bootstrap.css so dont just say inline css is best where you use it n number of pages and n number of lines

Comment: @Barthri Nathan, this is a datatable, why would you assume this will be used on multiple pages or even multiple lines?  The color of the cell is data in the example and is data in my answer. Data doesn't belong in css files, sure you can put it there. I imagine you put your content in css files also? That doesn't make it right.

Comment: i am just saying for styles. we can have single file for whole project even  or even for seperate modle to avoid confusion and better performance.but for few lines css file is not needed

Comment: Actually nothing changed the result is the same or better no popover is shown https://imgur.com/a/AULL0lr

Comment: Should the problem be that i color the cells dynamically throw jquery? or better from the form i set which cell to color and which not and even attach the data-content dynamically

Comment: @JohnKarry, I haven't seen your code but you probably rendered AFTER the popover() initializer was called. You need to call that on each new element created, after it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table border="1">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="background-color: red;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="IGOR" data-trigger="hover"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
 

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```